# jQuery Ajax call to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm new to Ajax and I'm trying to disable a checkbox if certain items are selected in a dropdown.  I need to pass in the mlaId to the GetMlaDeliveryType(int Id) method in the RecipientsController.cs.

I'm not exactly sure how to set  up the ajax call in the javascript function checkMlaDeliveryType(mlaId).

```
        //  MLA Add  disable express checkbox if delivery type is electronic
        $('.AddSelectedMla').change(function () {

            var deliveryType = checkMlaDeliveryType($('.AddSelectedMla').val());


            // disable express option if delivery type is Electronic
            if (deliveryType == "Mail") {
                $(".mlaExpressIndicator").removeAttr("disabled");
            }else{
                $(".mlaExpressIndicator").attr('checked', false).attr("disabled", true);
            }

        })

        // ajax call to get delivery type - "Mail" or "Electronic"
        function checkMlaDeliveryType(mlaId)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Recipients/GetMlaDeliveryType/" ,
                data: mlaId,
                dataType: ,
                success: 
            });

        }

RecipientsController.cs

    public string GetMlaDeliveryType(int Id) 
    {
        var recipientOrchestrator = new RecipientsOrchestrator();

        // Returns string "Electronic" or "Mail"
        return recipientOrchestrator.GetMlaDeliveryTypeById(Id);
    }
```

EDIT:

Here's how the final javascript looked that worked

```
//  MLA Add  disable express checkbox if delivery type is electronic
$('.AddSelectedMla').change(function () {

    checkMlaDeliveryType($('.AddSelectedMla').val());
})

// ajax call to get delivery type - "Mail" or "Electronic"
function checkMlaDeliveryType(mlaId)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMlaDeliveryType", "Recipients")',
        data: { id: mlaId },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            // disable express option if delivery type is Electronic
            if (result == "Mail") {
                $(".mlaExpressIndicator").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $(".mlaExpressIndicator").attr('checked', false).attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I was able to get mine working based on that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Recipients/GetMlaDeliveryType',
    data: { id: mlaId },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

then fix your controller action so that it returns an ActionResult, not a string. JSON would be appropriate in your case:

```
public string GetMlaDeliveryType(int Id) 
{
    var recipientOrchestrator = new RecipientsOrchestrator();

    // Returns string "Electronic" or "Mail"
    return Json(
        recipientOrchestrator.GetMlaDeliveryTypeById(Id), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Now your success callback will directly be passed a javascript instance of your model. You don't need to specify any `dataType` parameters:

```
success: function(result) {
    // TODO: use the result here to do whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: thanks, I still have one question.  How do I return the result?  I want the checkMlaDeliveryType to return the result.  in the success function is it just return result;  ??

Comment: No, you cannot return any result. AJAX is asynchronous meaning that you should manipulate the result only **inside** the `success` callback. You could also invoke some other function from the success callback which will perform the necessary operations on the result.

Answer (score 5):

Set `data` in the Ajax call so that its key matches the parameter on the controller (that is, `Id`):

```
data: { Id: mlaId },
```

Note also that it's a better practice to use `@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)` to get an Action URL:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetMlaDeliveryType", "Recipients")'
```