# Execute function from controller via Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.net MVC and I am trying to get a string from a c# function using Ajax I have tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559515/jquery-ajax-call-to-controller) but nothing seems to work.

**This is my controller function:**

```
public string Test()
    {
        string test = "hi";

        return test;
    }
```

**This is my script tag:**

```
<script>
    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textbox.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Home")',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("hi");
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` instead of just `return test`, just like in the solution you linked.

Comment: I'm using net.core so can't really use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Comment: Are there any console errors?  Have you verified the the ajax method is actually called? I'd add some logging to the javascript to verify the ajax method is being called

Comment: Hey the console does not give any errors but I'll do some breakpoints like how Jonathan suggested to see if it's actually being called.

Comment: tried to do that nothing seem unusual

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information presented to give an accurate solution. I created a local MVC application and added a Test() action method that returns a string and I was able to get the result with your ajax code.

A couple things you could try is:

1. Making sure the $.ajax actually gets called. So if you have surrounding logic make sure it hits it as expected
2. ajax has an error callback that you can add to the ajax call to see if there is an error. [This](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method) has an example how to use an error callback to see what is wrong

Comment: Edited to add my script tag, it doesn't seem like ajax is being called even tho the event is definitely being "called".

Comment: Run Fiddler. Is the `GET` request being passed through? Use Chrome Developer Tools and put a breakpoint on the `$.ajax` line. Is it getting hit? Put a breakpoint in your controller code. Is it getting hit? Trace the message from browser, to over the wire, to on the server for some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Place your `<script>` tags inside `@section` in the view and put `@RenderSection` at the bottom of `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
// in your view
@section Scripts {
    <script>
    // your script here
    ....
    </script>
}
```

Then put this is at the bottom of `_Layout.cshtml` and make sure it comes after jQuery:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

---

**Explanation**

My guess is jQuery is not loaded when the the DOM parses your javascript.  If this is the case the your `$.ajax` call will never work.

The current Visual Studio MVC templates (for .Net-core) place jQuery at the bottom of `_Layout.cshtml`.  If you place `<script>` tags in the middle of your view, they will appear before jQuery is requested by the browser.

Placing the `<script>` tags inside a `@section Scripts { }` element means that the javascript will actually be added to `_Layout.cshtml` in the location specified by `@RenderSection("Scripts")`.